Experiencing Nautilus Bug With Thunar
I'm experiencing exactly this bug, but on Xubuntu (Thunar instead of Nautilus), and only when trying to open a file or folder in VScode Insiders (installed via Snap). From within other Snap applications, like Firefox, I can browse folders containing JS or JSON files just fine. In the bug report it says upgrading glib from 2.78 to 2.80 fixed the problem, but I think my glib is already on 2.80?
$ apt list --installed | grep libglib2.0


WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libglib2.0-0t64/noble-updates,noble-security,now 2.80.0-6ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libglib2.0-bin/noble-updates,noble-security,now 2.80.0-6ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libglib2.0-data/noble-updates,noble-security,now 2.80.0-6ubuntu3.1 all [installed,automatic]

Could it be that the code-insiders package uses an old version of glib? Anything else I can do?
